How can I save the full filename in a register
It's often convenient to print the full filename in Vim. Sometimes, I want to save this into a register. Here's what I do:
1 ^g (1, then control-g)
Then I can select the filename with my mouse and copy to the OS clipboard. However, I want to do this without using a mouse.
I know I can print the filename using :put %, then I can yank into my clipboard using "*yy - but how do I put the full path into my clipboard?


I know I can print the filename using :put %, then I can yank into my clipboard using "*yy - but how do I put the full path into my clipboard?

You can manipulate registers from command line:
:let @*=expand("%:p")

or
:call setreg("*", expand("%:p"))

Using either of above, map 2<Ctrl-G>
nnoremap 2<C-g> <cmd>let @*=expand("%:p")<CR>


As an aside, is C- the "standard" way to write control in Vim? With showcmd it displays ^, but in the vimscript you use C-.

@sdpoll see :h key-notation

One option is to make a command that prints the full file. Here is an example using <leader> (by default set to \).
noremap <leader>f :put =expand('%:p')<cr>

This will insert the full filename in the file, and you can yank into whichever register you like. More info on filename expansion can be found here or in the documentation with :h expand.
